# awk command print the file content while executing with sudo bash in ub20.04

Tags: bash, awk, sudo

I have a .txt file containing following:

```
Depends: abc
Depends: def
Depends: ghi
```

I am using ub20.04

While executing following command:

```
cat demo.txt | awk -F'Depends:' 'NF > 1 {print $2}'
```

I get output as follows:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

But while running:

```
sudo -s bash -c "cat demo.txt | awk -F'Depends:' 'NF > 1 {print $2}'"
```

awk command is not working(it is just print the content of the file), output:

```
Depends: abc
Depends: def
Depends: ghi
```

Comment: `sudo awk -F'Depends:' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' demo.txt` works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> awk command is not working(it is just print the content of the file), output:

It is due to the presence of `$2` inside the double quotes which is expanded by shell and evaluating to an empty string and then `print $2` is becoming just `print`, which will obvious print full line.

```bash
sudo awk -F 'Depends:' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' demo.txt
```

Or better use `sed`:

```bash
sudo sed 's/^Depends: //' demo.txt
```

Note that `cat` is totally unnecessary as both awk and sed can directly operate on a file.

Comment: Adding a backslash before `$2` doesn't actually work when passed to `sudo -s bash -c`.

Comment: Curiously, adding a backslash does work when passed to `sudo bash -c`. Spawning a new shell with the `-s` option just to execute another layer of `bash` shell is wholly redundant anyway. And spawning a shell to execute `awk` is also unnecessary to begin with. Simply do `sudo awk -F' Depends:' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' demo.txt` if you want to stick to `awk`.

Comment: Very good point @blhsing. I should have spotted that `bash-c` is not really needed